# Cancel Edit Row Data table prime faces

Tags: primefaces, datatable

I have data table is filled dynamically with records.I add ajax request on that data table on rowEdit event.
I want on the method that handle rowEdit event in the back bean to check on some criteria and if it true don't edit this row 
i am using PF 3.1
thanks

```
<p:dataTable id="itemDT" var="item"  value="#{itemView.items}" selectionMode="multiple"
        selection="#{itemView.selectedItems}" 
        rowKey="#{item.Id}">
    <p:ajax event="rowEdit"
            listener="#{itemView.onRowEdit}" />
    <p:column headerText="Input three">
        <h:outputText value="#{item.inpt3}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Input four">
        <h:outputText value="#{item.inpt4}" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

and the back bean

```
    @ManagedBean(name="itemView")
@ViewScoped
public class ItemView{
    private ItemModel selectedItems[];
    // getters and setters for selectedItems
    private List<ItemModel> items;
    // getters and setters for items

    public void add(){
        // add item to i.e database
    }

    public void insertRecord(){
        // add itemModels  to items list 
    }
    public void onRowEdit(RowEditEvent event) {
           //check if criteria then cancel editing
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the third post about the same subject by you in one day! Any reason for that?

Comment: this is not the same post .i want to prevent to on row edit event only.

Comment: Ok,sorry then but please reply to the other questions to before/in addition to asking new questions. And keep in mind that using a prehistoric version of pf will reduce your chance of getting help